# How to uncheck the checkbox within the grid view template field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have two check boxes with the GridView TemplateField. I want to uncheck the checked boxes after submission. My gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="ShiftID" 
Width="177px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="ChbGrid" runat="server" 
          oncheckedchanged="ChbGrid_CheckedChanged" />
           </ItemTemplate>
           <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChbGridHead" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 
          Font-Bold="True" oncheckedchanged="ChbGridHead_CheckedChanged" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried in below mentioned methode

```
 public void checkboxclear()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChbGrid");
            if(chkrow.Checked==true)
            {
                chkrow.Checked = false;//it works 
            }
            else 
            {
                CheckBox chkrow1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChbGridHead");
                if (chkrow1.Checked == true)
                {
                    chkrow1.Checked = false;//it shows error like "Object reference not set to instance of an object"
                }
            }  
        }
```

How can I improve my code to solve this issue?  Why I am unable to call these check boxes inside the  aspx.cs page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the `RowType` becuase your second checkbox is in the `HeaderTemplate`. For that `gridview` generates special `HeaderRow`. That you can directly access and set the value to it.

```
public void checkboxclear()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChbGrid");
               if(chkrow.Checked)
                chkrow.Checked = false;
            }
        }  
      CheckBox chkrow1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ChbGridHead");
       if (chkrow1.Checked)
            chkrow1.Checked = false;
    }
```

Also you don't need to use the `chkrow.Checked==true`. `chkrow.Checked` it returns `boolean` value so that direactly should check in `if` condition.

Comment: The header selection still stays

Comment: What do you mean by `still stays ` ?

Comment: ,Header selection means If I select this, all other check box will fill automatically. But When I submit the page,sub check boxes getting unchecked and header check box still stays as checked.

Comment: The grid view headerrow is special and can be accessed directly, see my answer.

Comment: @Coder of Code, It works fine now..Plz add "l" for findcontrol in your answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't know when you are calling this function, but the correct place to pre-set values is in the row databound event.

Having said that the reason your code is blowing up is that you are looking for the header check box in every row, and it is only in the header row. Just access the header through the gridviews header property and do your find control there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like

```
    CheckBox chkHeader = (CheckBox)Gridview1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ChbGridHead");
```